# How to create a mp3-clip from an existing mp3?

Tags: software-recommendation, mp3

Is there a free audio tool where I can just grab a snippet from a mp3 file and save it as a new mp3?

Answer (score 5):

Open it in QuickTime Player, click **Edit → Trim…** (⌘T), drag the yellow handles to truncate it to the snippet you want, and export the result.

[image: QuickTime trimming]

Note that it will export in AAC (`.m4a`) format, so if you need MP3, you'll need to convert it afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

"Audacity" is also a good [tool for audio editing](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/).  It has an "Export Selection..." menu item that supports MP3, including tag editing.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use GarageBand, included with the iLife suite with Mac computers.

1. In Garageband go the beginning of the sample you want and press ⌘T.
2. Select the first cut section, and press delete.
3. Do the same at the end of the sample you want.
4. Select menu item `Share > Send Song to iTunes…`, in the following popup make sure your `Compress Using:` setting is set to `MP3 Encoder`. Hit the `Share` button.

Answer (score 0):

[Macsome audio editor](http://www.macsome.com/audio-editor-mac/index.html) is freeware and will allow you select a portion of your audio file, then use "Save Selection..." to export as mp3 or aac.

[image]